# How to save each output whenever I run a program without losing the previous output?

Tags: matlab

How to save each output whenever I run a program without losing the previous output?

Example:

```
  load('ii.mat','j')
  k(j)=p(i);
  j=j+1;
  save('output','k'); 
  save('ii',j);
```

This idea doesn't work. It replaces the previous value.

Comment: save by different names. For example, generate name as follows: `savefile=['output' num2str(j) '.mat']; save(savefile,'k');`

Comment: thanx for the help..... but, why we can't use the value of 'j'??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `matfile` command instead of load and save. This way, you can insert your data into the existing file:

```
%open or create file:
m = matfile(filename,'Writable',1)
%directly write to file:
m.k(j)=p(i)
```